# GridView missing data between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

So basically I am doing a manage packaging item system. The scenario is, when I select from gvSPU, gvFinalised should display the item in database. After that, when I add new item into the gvFinalised, it supposed to keep stacking up the items instead of wiping out the previous record and display the added latest one. Here is the code:

```
private List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> tempDistSPUI
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["tempDistSPUI"] == null)
        {
            return new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>)ViewState["tempDistSPUI"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["tempDistSPUI"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gvSPU_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    SPUname = this.gvSPU.DataKeys[rowNo].Value.ToString();
    lblSPUname.Text = SPUname;

    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> templist = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
    templist = tempDistSPUI;

    templist = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);
    gvFinalised.DataSource = templist;
    gvFinalised.DataBind();

    this.tempDistSPUI = templist;
}
```

When gvSPU row is selected, it should store all the records into templist and display in gvFinalised.

```
List<string> prodVariantIDList = new List<string>();
private List<string> SelectedVariantDetailIDs
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] == null)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<string>)ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] = value;
    }
}

protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail = new List<ProductPacking>();

    int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    // get the last product variant IDs from ViewState
    prodVariantIDList = this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs;

    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
            //Prevent gvFinalised to store duplicate products
            if (cb.Checked && !prodVariantIDList.Any(i => i == gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
            {
                // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
    {
        prodVariantDetail.Add(prodPackBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));
    }

    gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
    gvFinalised.DataBind();

    // save prodVariantIDList to ViewState
    this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs = prodVariantIDList;
}
```

When add button is on click, it should append with the record in gridview instead of wiping them off and insert the checked one.

I am using the viewState to store the record between postbacks. However, when I try to add new item into gvFinalised, the previous record which in the templist will disappear and the gvFinalised will be populated with the result from prodVariantDetail list.

Any guide? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> itemList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
protected void gvSPU_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

        int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        SPUname = this.gvSPU.DataKeys[rowNo].Value.ToString();
        lblSPUname.Text = SPUname;

        itemList = tempDistSPUI;

        itemList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);
        gvFinalised.DataSource = itemList;
        gvFinalised.DataBind();

        this.tempDistSPUI = itemList;
    }

    protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> prodVariantDetail = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

        int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

        // get the last product variant IDs from ViewState
        prodVariantIDList = this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs;

        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                //Prevent gvFinalised to store duplicate products
                if (cb.Checked && !prodVariantIDList.Any(i => i == gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                    prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
        {
            prodVariantDetail.Add(packBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < itemList.Count; j++)
        {
            prodVariantDetail.Add(itemList[j]);
        }

        gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
        gvFinalised.DataBind();

        }

        // save prodVariantIDList to ViewState
        this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs = prodVariantIDList;
    }
```

Comment: Do you set `SelectedVariantDetailIDs` anywhere else? Perhaps in `Page_Load`?

Comment: Nope, I did not. I only set it once the add button is on click. I can add multiple times and the records will be stacked.

Comment: Just that it will wiped out the records in templist which I shows previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the elements of `tempDistSPUI` into `prodVariantDetail` before binding `prodVariantDetail` to `gvFinalised`.

Here's what I would do using [List.AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> prodVariantDetail = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

    int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    // get the last product variant IDs from ViewState
    prodVariantIDList = this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs;

    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
            //Prevent gvFinalised to store duplicate products
            if (cb.Checked && !prodVariantIDList.Any(i => i == gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
            {
                // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
    {
        prodVariantDetail.Add(packBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));
    }

    // get the content of tempDistSPUI from ViewState
    itemList = this.tempDistSPUI;

    // add all elements of itemList to prodVariantDetail
    prodVariantDetail.AddRange(itemList);

    gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
    gvFinalised.DataBind();

    // save prodVariantIDList to ViewState
    this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs = prodVariantIDList;
}
```

Comment: No no no, what I mean is first I display the gvFinalised with templist. After that, I add in some item into prodVariantDetail list. Then I want to display both the item from templist and prodvariantDetail list instead of prodVariantDetail list. Cause my current code first the gvFinalised will be populated by templist. After add, the gvFinalised will be populated by prodVariantDetails but not the record in templist

Comment: In `gvSPU_OnRowCommand` you bind a `List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>` to `gvFinalised`, but in `lbnAdd_Click` you bind a `List<ProductPacking>` to `gvFinalised`, why is that and what's the relation between `DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems` and `ProductPacking`?

Comment: Because when I select from gvSPU, I display the item in templist and populate the gvFinalised with templist first. Then after that, I got another gridview which allow me to select add-on items. When finish selecting add-on items group by category, I add them into a prodVariantDetail list. Then I wanted to append the prodVariantDetail list to gvFinalised

Comment: Are you saying that when `lbnAdd_Click` is executed, `gvFinalised` must contain all elements from `prodVariantDetail` and `templist`? If so, how is it possible since `prodVariantDetail` and `templist` are different types? If you want to combine `prodVariantDetail` and `templist`, then both of them must be the same type.

Comment: Oh okay. I amended them to become same type and I added a for loop to transfer item from templist into prodVariantDetail list. However, it still does not work. See edited portion